# Failed to build apk via Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build apk from my Ionic project via gradle but it shows the following error:-

[image: APK build Failed]

Note: I've tried the following solutions  which didn't work for me:-

1) Removed nodejs, clear all directories related to nodejs, cordova, ionic, gradle and do fresh installation.

2) Change distribution url in graddle-wrapper.properties file in project folder to **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip** and build again.

3) Installed ant4windows and executed **$ rm -r ~/.gradle** and hoping that ant will do the magic.

4) Downloaded gradle-2.12-bin.zip & replaced the 'gradle 2.2.1 zip' file in PC-User/.gradle/.. folder . but it still fetches gradle 2.2.1 zip & shows exception

Some days ago I successfully created my apk following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVOwGyQB3DQ & the apk was built using ant. Also tell why gradle is taking over the ant this time?

Comment: Looks like the gradle dist zip downloaded/failed to unzip. Manually download the zip and then change distribution url to point to your locally downloaded .zip

Comment: Since you are already using ionic, why not use `ionic build android`?